# Why is maven downloading multiple versions of a dependency when I the first time I run the versions-maven-plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I'm trying to remove a version of commons-beanutils from being installed into my local .m2 repo due to a known vulnerability https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-45/product_id-33761/Apache-Commons-Beanutils.html.

However, the first time I use the versions-maven-plugin to version my artifacts it automatically downloads multiple versions the dependency.

```
Downloaded from maven: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.9.3/commons-beanutils-1.9.3.pom (15 kB at 29 kB/s)
Downloading from maven: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.7.0/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.pom
Downloaded from maven: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.7.0/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.pom (357 B at 6.4 kB/s)
Downloading from maven: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.6/commons-beanutils-1.6.pom
Downloaded from maven: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-beanutils/1.6/commons-beanutils-1.6.pom (2.3 kB at 50 kB/s)
Downloading from maven: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.9.3/commons-beanutils-1.9.3.jar
Downloaded from maven: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.9.3/commons-beanutils-1.9.3.jar (246 kB at 1.8 MB/s)
```

I've tried overriding the version of the dependency of the plugin in the pom file.

```
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7</version>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
                            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
                            <version>1.9.3</version>
                            <scope>compile</scope>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
```

But it still pulls down the multiple versions.

Anyone have an explanation for why the maven downloads multiple versions of the same dependency even when a particular version is specified.

To be clear, the plugin resolves to use the correct version of 1.9.3, I'm just wondering why multiple versions of the dependency are downloaded in the first place?

Cheers

Comment: In your snippet, I see multiple different POMs, but only one JAR.

Comment: Could well be transient dependencies, a `mvn dependency:tree` will probably give you a bit more information

Comment: You could check effective pom using `mvn help:effective-pom` to see if multiple versions of this dependency exists in pom. Also, as rightly pointed out above, please check all transitive dependencies using `mvn dependency:tree`